# PowerShell InvokeGet the directory property cannot be found

Tags: powershell

We needed to retrieve the information in active directory concerning 'Terminal Services'. For this I've created a function that works fine most of the time. However, with some users we have issues.

**The code:**

```
Function Get-ADTSProfile {
               [CmdletBinding()]
            Param(
                [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
                [String] $DistinguishedName,
                [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
                [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
                [ValidateSet('UserProfile','AllowLogon','HomeDirectory','HomeDrive')]
                [String]$Property
            )
            Begin {
                $User = [ADSI]"LDAP://$DistinguishedName"
            }
            Process {
                Switch ($Property) {
                    'AllowLogon'    {if ($($User.psbase.InvokeGet('allowLogon')) -eq '1'){$True}else{$False}}
                    'HomeDirectory' {$User.psbase.InvokeGet('TerminalServicesHomeDirectory')}
                    'HomeDrive'     {$User.psbase.InvokeGet('TerminalServicesHomeDrive')}
                    'UserProfile'   {$User.psbase.InvokeGet('TerminalServicesProfilePath')}
                }   
            }
        }
```

**The error:**

```
Get-ADTSProfile -DistinguishedName 'CN=test\, test (Den Bosch) NLD,OU=Users,OU=Disabled,OU=NLD,OU=EU,DC=domain,DC=net' -Property 'UserProfile'
Exception calling "InvokeGet" with "1" argument(s): "The directory property cannot be fo
und in the cache.
"
At S:\Test\Brecht\Testie.ps1:84 char:38
+                     'UserProfile'   {$User.psbase.InvokeGet('TerminalServicesPro ...
+                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodTargetInvocation
```

I can't really figure out why it works on some and not on all..

Comment: It seems like this only happens on user objects where the 'User Profile' is blank AND where it has never been filled in before. So to speak, it will only happen for brand new users that don't have a 'User Profile' set. Need to figure out how to achieve a blank result in that case instead of an error..

Comment: Very strange, I have a user where 'Allow logon to terminal server' is checked ON, but it's still giving an error. But for some other users where it's also ON it works fine.

Comment: can this  help you? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243440

Comment: Thanks CB, trying to figure it out as the example is a bit difficult to understand in C++. [This](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebookv2/archive/2012/03/25/chapter-19-user-management.aspx) seems to be related, it talks about GetEx() but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: It's even the same message when using the `Get-QadUser test | Select-Object Expandproperty TSAllowLogon`. Fails on some, not on all. Must be an issue in out AD I guess..

Comment: It fails only for user that never had this property set. if you do ` (Get-QadUser test ).TSAllowLogon -eq $null` it returns `true`. There are many parameters in AD that have this behaviour, you have to jest test for $null before retrive the value. Hope can helps!

Comment: That seems like a good solution. although I hate being dependent on third party snapins so I tried `$User.psbase.InvokeGet('allowLogon') -eq $null` without luck. Maybe I just need to use the Quest Snapin then :(

Comment: Played a bit more with it and it seems that it returns `True` in case the field isn't set. The weird thing is, in our AD the field says `Allow logon to terminal server = ON`. So I might just go with a `Try\Catch` and report `couldn't retrieve` if it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been working on a recent project that uses ADSI to set and read Terminal Services attributes. From my testing anytime you perform a "InvokeGet({TS Attribute})" a COM exception will be thrown with the message "The directory property cannot be found in cache"

This seems to occur only when the "userParameters" attribute is not set in AD. Maybe the attribute internally checks the ADSI cache for userParameters? So i'm thinking logically you could check the DirectoryEntry for userParameters first, then try and read the properties, or else set it to construct the blob

```
if ($user.Properties.Contains("userParameters"))
{
 #Read the Property from ADSI
 Write-Host $user.InvokeGet("TerminalServicesProfilePath")
} else {
 #Set the property to construct the userParameter blob
 $user.InvokeSet("TerminalServicesProfilePath", "\\somepath")
 $user.CommitChanges()
}
```

Even if the userParameters attribute is not set, you can still perform an InvokeSet to have it constructed