# query extensionattribute1 fail empty variable

Tags: powershell

I have a question about an error when obtaining the value from extensionattribute1 from AD, if the extensionattribute1 is populated the script runs fine, if extensionattribute1 is not configured or "cleared" I get an error, its not a fatal error where the script terminates, its still completes, but I would like to understand the error and prevent it.

```
$User = (((New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($Null, $LdapFilter)).FindOne()).GetDirectoryEntry())
    $ext1 = $User.get("extensionAttribute1")
```

The error message is as follows:

```
Exception calling "get" with "1" argument(s): "The directory property cannot be found in the cache.
"
At C:\gavin\audit_1.2_.ps1:161 char:2
+     $ext1 = $User.get("extensionAttribute1")
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseAdapterMethodInvokeTI
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not use the `ActiveDirectory` module? Maybe you are using PS 6/7 on Linux.

Comment: @Midacts, I am using powershell version 2 and I do not have the facilty/option to load the modules.

Comment: This change has fixed it, but why ?
`
$ext1 = $User.invokeget("extensionAttribute1")
`
changed the .get to .invokeget

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell InvokeGet the directory property cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26160791/powershell-invokeget-the-directory-property-cannot-be-found) (instead of `TerminalServicesProfilePath` use: `extensionattribute1`)